# Obtener el valor de los parámetros de una función de JavaScript dentro de un texto en C#

Tags: c#, regex

He evaluado una expresión regular en distintas páginas online de expresiones regulares y funciona correctamente.

El problema es cuando la ejecuto en C#, que no me entrega resultados.

Este es mi código de ejemplo

```cs
string html = "<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
setHash('9cd117bb2969f768d71850b096e47f96','636222625703335366');
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>"
string pattern = @"[^setHash][0-9 a-z]*','[0-9]*'[)]{0};";

Regex regExp = new Regex(pattern); 

Match match = regExp.Match(html); //no se encuentra.
```

Quizás estoy haciendo algo mal y es por eso que recurro a los gurus.

[image: Captura de coincidencia probada en regexr.com].

Comment: ¿Qué texto estás intentando validar contra la expresión regular?

Comment: string html = "<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
setHash('9cd117bb2969f768d71850b096e47f96','636222625703335366');
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>";

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que se desea que coincida? ¿Cuál el el objetivo? ... Y ¿realmente estás usando ese código con el string mal declarado, o eso fue un ejemplo rápido que redactaste para preguntar?

Comment: Estimado, gracias por responder. Te cuento: Estoy tratando de extraer los valores que ejecuta una funcion javascript. setHash('9cd117bb2969f768d71850b096e47f96','6362226257033353‌​66'); Solo necesito los valores que esta funcion se esta ejecutando. Es por eso que estoy ejecutando esta expresion regular. Gracias

Comment: @ctm002 el objeto `html` no es un string válido. Se cierran las comillas antes de tiempo y tiene retornos de carro... ¿querías usar un literal de cadena crudo? Esos empiezan con `@`.

Comment: Me explico: la variable html es de tipo string y guarda el contenido de una pagina html.  Ahora lo que necesito es poder recuperar los valores que se   pasan a la funcion setHash.

Comment: tu `pattern` tiene ";" al final tal vez por eso no te devuelva nada

Comment: Acabo de quitar los dos puntos y nada!!!. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @ctm002 hice un fiddle de c# en consola y quitando el punto y coma funciona bien https://dotnetfiddle.net/B7LvW1 aclaro que he agregado `"` y `"+` en el texto para unirlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que la expresión regular que estás intentando, si bien puede coincidir con el texto, no funciona como estás pensando.

Por ejemplo, `[^setHash]` sólo coincide con 1 caracter que no sea ni `s`, ni `e`, ni `t`, etc. Además, el cuantificador `{0}` hace que no estés buscando el paréntesis final. En definitiva, no creo que sea el objetivo buscado.

Para ingresar texto literal en una expresión regular, simplemente se usa el texto. Los únicos caracteres que tienen un significado especial en regex son:

```
 \   ^   $   .   |   ?   *   +   (   )   [   {
```

La forma en que te recomendaría realizarlo es:

**Regex:**

```
^\s*setHash\s*\(\s*['"]([0-9a-z]*)['"]\s*,\s*['"]([0-9]*)['"]\s*\)\s*;
```

- `^` - Inicio de la línea.
- `\s*` - Cualquier cantidad de espacios en blanco.
  Esta estructura se repite en cada parte donde pueda aparecer (lo obviaremos en esta descripción para simplificar)
- `setHash` - Literal.
- `\(` - Paréntesis literal.
- `['"]([0-9a-f]*)['"]` - Primer parámetro entre comillas (simples o dobles).
  Al estar entre paréntesis, captura el texto en el primer grupo.

  - `[0-9a-f]*` 0 o más caracteres hexadecimales.
- `,` - Coma literal.
- `['"]([0-9]*)['"]` - Segundo parámetro entre comillas (simples o dobles).
  Al estar entre paréntesis, captura el texto en el segundo grupo.

  - `[0-9]*` 0 o más dígitos.
- `\);` - Paréntesis y punto y coma literal.

**Código:**

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

```cs
string pattern = @"^\s*setHash\s*\(\s*['""]([0-9a-f]*)['""]\s*,\s*['""]([0-9]*)['""]\s*\)\s*;";
string html  = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
//<![CDATA[
setHash('9cd117bb2969f768d71850b096e47f96','636222625703335366');
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>";

Match m = Regex.Match(html, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Primer parámetro: {0}\nSegundo parámetro: {1}", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2]);
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Primer parámetro: 9cd117bb2969f768d71850b096e47f96
Segundo parámetro: 636222625703335366
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/tUwDZv

Comment: Master, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Tené en cuenta que esta solución apuntaba a explicar el porqué estaba fallando y cómo sería una expresión regular que coincida con lo que estabas buscando. En textos muy largos, la solución de [Konamiman](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48802/127) seguramente se ejecuta más rápido.

Answer (score 3):

Yo no usaría expresiones regulares para un problema relativamente sencillo como este. El siguiente código es más largo, pero me ha llevado menos tiempo escribirlo del que he usado intentanto arreglar tu regex:

```
String html = @"<script type=""text / javascript"">
//<![CDATA[
setHash('9cd117bb2969f768d71850b096e47f96', '636222625703335366');
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</ script > ";

var inicio = html.IndexOf("setHash(")+8;
var fin = html.IndexOf(")", inicio);
var valores = html.Substring(inicio, fin-inicio).Split(',');
var valoresSinComillas = valores.Select(v => v.Trim('\'', ' ', '"'));
```

En `valoresSinComillas` tienes todos los parámetros pasados a `setHash`, sean dos o cero o cualquier cantidad. Fíjate que por robustez he añadido la comprobación de las comillas dobles, que también son delimitadores de cadena legales en JavaScript.

Por supuesto, si esperas que algún valor puede no estar entre comillas (porque sea un número o una variable) tendrás que hacer algunos cambios, pero este código te puede servir de punto de partida.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Creo que tu solución es bastante buena. Pero al fin pude la pude solucionar!!. Si le sirve a alguien la publico aquí.  @"[ ^setHash(] [0-9 a-z]*','[0-9]*'[)]{0}",